# "Actions-on-google:error No user object" issue

Tags: google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have lately been experimenting around (as a noob!) with Webhook. However, I seem to be stuck with an "actions-on-google:error No user object" issue.
Would appreciate if you could reach out and lend a hand please.

[firebase log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCLTL.png)
[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgJxn.png)

Comment: Can you add what you are getting in your console.log? (The response/body - seems to be empty...)

Comment: Do you get other errors down the log file? I had the same problem. It took me a while to figure out that other errors down the log file indicate that action name was missing. I added the action name in DialogFlow and it "fixed" the problem

Answer (score 0):

The inline editor uses Firebase Cloud Functions and the issue is that Firebase isn't allowing you to make external requests ( `EXT_PRAYER_TIME_API_URL = ...`) with the current plan ([see Cloud Function Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)). You need to setup a billing account with your project and change your plan to one that allows you to make outbound requests.